# SQL to Linq Lambda with Multiple Tables, Cases, and Aggregate (Group By, Count)

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

Given the following tables:

| UnitAlertStatus |
| --- |
| ID |
| AlertedUnitID |
| UnitAlertStatus |
| EpochStamp |

| Unit |
| --- |
| ID |
| HardwareID |
| Name |
| UnitTypeID |

| UnitType |
| --- |
| ID |
| Name |

What would the equivalent LINQ Lambda be for the following SQL?

```
Select [AlertedUnitID]
, Count(case when [AlertStatus] = 1 then [UnitAlertStatus].[ID] end) as Count_Caution
, Count(case when [AlertStatus] = 3 then [UnitAlertStatus].[ID] end) as Count_Alarm
, Count(case when [AlertStatus] = 7 then [UnitAlertStatus].[ID] end) as Count_Critical
, [Unit].[HardwareID] as Unit_HardwareID, [Unit].[Name] as Unit_Name, [UnitType].[Name] As UnitType_Name
From [UnitAlertStatus], [Unit], [UnitType]
Where [UnitAlertStatus].[AlertedUnitID] = [Unit].[ID] And [UnitType].[ID] = [Unit].[UnitTypeID] And [EpochStamp] > 1698150366500
Group By [AlertedUnitID], [Unit.HardwareID], [Unit].[Name], [UnitType].[Name]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = context.UnitAlertStatus
    .Join(context.Unit, uas => uas.AlertedUnitID, u => e.ID, (uas, u) => new { uas, u })
    .Join(context.UnitType, temp => temp.u.UnitTypeID, ut => ut.ID, (temp, ut) => new { temp.uas, temp.u, ut })
    .Where(joined => joined.uas.EpochStamp > 1698150366500)
    .GroupBy(joined => new
    {
        AlertedUnitID = joined.uas.AlertedUnitID,
        Unit_HardwareID = joined.u.HardwareID,
        Unit_Name = joined.u.Name,
        UnitType_Name = joined.ut.Name
    })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        AlertedUnitID = group.Key.AlertedUnitID,
        Count_Caution = group.Count(g => g.uas.AlertStatus == 1),
        Count_Alarm = group.Count(g => g.uas.AlertStatus == 3),
        Count_Critical = group.Count(g => g.uas.AlertStatus == 7),
        Unit_HardwareID = group.Key.Unit_HardwareID,
        Unit_Name = group.Key.Unit_Name,
        UnitType_Name = group.Key.UnitType_Name
    });
```

In the above, we first join the `UnitAlertStatus`, `Unit`, and `UnitType` tables, apply the `Where` filter, group the results by the specified columns, and then use `Count` to calculate the counts for different `AlertStatus` values.